# Java interface generics where implementing classes define the type

Tags: java

I'm trying to design some interfaces for a library that will support multiple storage systems for it's data - like mysql, or mongo.

I'm trying to design a single `Model` interface so that anyone using my API can see what data is available. The problem is that the `ID` or primary key type varies. For example from mysql it'll be a `Long` and mongo uses ObjectId, etc.

I was thinking I could handle this with generics, but I'm not sure this is the right approach. I don't want to have to cast all the time to get the right ID types.

Is this an acceptable approach or should I be using something else? I don't want to build my APIs with this approach and then run into issues and have to redo it all.

The dog model interface:

```
public interface DogModel<T> {
    T getId();
}
```

The sql-specific dog model:

```
public class SqlDogModel implements DogModel<Long> {
    private final Long id;

    public SqlDogModel(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

How I declare the model in the general storage interface:

```
public interface StorageAdapter {
    Optional<DogModel> getDog(String name);
}
```

Comment: Your `StorageAdapter` also needs to be generic: `StorageAdapter<T>`. If you don't want that, then perhaps rethink your premise.

Comment: Ah, that does work. It's compiling anyway, whether that's a good approach is unclear.

Comment: Perhaps you should define what you mean by "good".

Comment: Not sure, simpler? Not misusing the language somehow, java pros looking at it and laughing.

Answer (score 1):

It can be made simpler:
An abstract class can implement an interface, but in my example I have the getter and setter logic in the base class and this can't happen in the interface as interfaces don't have logic.

```
public abstract class DogModel < T > {
T id;
public T getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(T id) {
    this.id = id;
}}

public class SqlDogModel extends DogModel < Long > {}
```